# Iterating on spatial point grid with dynamic buffer to find intersection in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I have a fairly complex problem that I don't really know where to start. I have a set of spatial points (X & Y) coordinates that also include information (Height).

```
set.seed(12345)
X = runif(100,  0, 45)
Y = runif(100, 0, 45)
Height = runif(100, 6, 9)
data <- data.frame("X" = X, "Y" = Y, "Height" = Height)
data$Radius_max = 1/3 * data$Height
```

The coordinates look something like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y)) +
geom_point()
```

[image]

For each point, I need a buffer that is scaled by Height. The buffer is an equation that is scaled by height but is essentially a circular buffer similar to a cone. The following steps are what I've come up with to determine buffer size for each point:

1. Set bottom left point to radius_max.
2. Find the intersection of the radius at any given point relative to the next point.
3. Do this multiple times to refit a new radius for the intial point relative to new adjacent radii.

The reason for starting at an initial point is that each radii following will be constrained by the neighboring points (randomly generating points may or may not have this effect). No cone can be below another cone. Think trees. If possible, I would like to know the radius at 45 degree increments.

I'm ok with any solution and suspect there may be a way to do this with the spatial packages rather than doing some by hand. Where do I start?

Comment: What is a "buffer"? Just a list of points that are close to a given point?

Comment: Each point has a radius_max, but the radius will be reduced if a point is close to another point.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what is a "buffer" in your problem and what do you want to achieve. Maybe it is something from a domain I have no knowledge of. It might help if you could define your objective in terms that are more common.

Comment: I suppose intlstead of a buffer it would be more of a circular  polygon or raster. The XY coordinates are trees and I need to find the intersection of each polygon

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are after. Particularly the 45 degrees increments. Do you want the buffer to be circular? If so, perhaps the below is a solution.

Your example data

```
set.seed(12345)
X <- runif(100,  0, 45)
Y <- runif(100, 0, 45)
Height <- runif(100, 6, 9)
data <- data.frame("X" = X, "Y" = Y, "Height" = Height)
data$Radius_max <- 1/3 * data$Height
```

Possible solution

```
library(raster)
x <- pointDistance(data[,1:2], lonlat=FALSE)
diag(x) <- NA
mn <- apply(x, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)
data$radius <- pmin(data$Radius_max, mn/2)
d <- SpatialPoints(data[, c('X', 'Y')], proj4string=CRS('+proj=utm +zone=1'))
b <- buffer(d, data$radius, dissolve=FALSE)
plot(b)
```